# mysql slow queries not writing to log

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5

I have the following slow query information setup in mysql.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%SLOW%';

Variable_name     Value 
log_slow_queries  ON 
slow_launch_time  2
slow_query_log    ON 
slow_query_log_file   /var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log
```

The log file has the following premissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Sep 11 14:31 slow-queries.log
```

The my.cnf file looks like this:

```
back_log = 2000
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = 1
long_query_time = 1 
general_log = 1
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log
```

From mytop I can see that I have slow queries, but I don't see anything writing to the logs.

Comment: What user is mysql running as? The log should be owned by that user.

Comment: NathanC is right slow-quesries.log needs to be mysql:mysql

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, your problem is probably because of the the permissions 
on the log file.

If mysql runs under the "mysql" user, as it normally does, you can change the file 
ownership thusly:

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log
```